# Spark Repeating `DataFrame` Processing Work?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Apache Spark (1.6) for a ML task and I noticed that Spark seems to be repeating processing on a single `DataFrame`.

My code looks something like this:

```
val df1 = sqlContext.read.parquet("data.parquet")

val df2 = df1.withColumn("new", explode(expensiveTextProcessing($"text"))

println(df2.count)

... (no changes to df2)

println(df2.count)
```

So I know that my `withColumn` is a transformation and `count` is an action so the `count` will seem like the longer operation.

However, I noticed that the second time I run `df2.count` takes just as long as the first `df2.count`. Additionally, a NLP tool I am using throws a few warnings during `expensiveTextProcessing` and these warnings show up during **both** of the `count` calls.

Is Spark doing all of the `expensiveTextProcessing` each time I use the data in `df2`?

(for more context you can see my actual Jupyter Notebook [here](https://github.com/EvanOman/KaggleCompetitions/blob/master/StackExchange/scala/Modeling.ipynb))

Comment: Did you try to persist the dataframe at any point? If not, why do you expect it to be quicker?

Comment: Hmm, so all of the work done to do `count` is discarded if I do not use `persist`? That is a pretty important point I somehow missed...

Comment: I mean, `count()` is an action, yes. The transformations are lazy. Even if you didn't modify the dataframe, the count would still have to collect all the records

Comment: Sometimes the data is stored in the memory cache, but that is not something you can rely on in any capacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataFrame like RDD has lineage which used to built resulting DataFrame during action call. As you call count the results from all executors are collected to driver. You can check Spark Web UI DAG representation and staging of DataFrame and also duration and localization of processes in order to implement transformations.